# Python translation using goslate

Tags: python, goslate

i am building a translator that translates user input to french using python. I am however encountering a challenge where my goslate function does not catch user input and translate it. I will appreciate your help.

```
import goslate
gs = goslate.Goslate()

text = input("please input the word you would like translated:\n")
gs.translate(text,'fr')
```

Comment: Do you mean when you run the above code you don't see anything on the output console? If that's the case check @trivvz answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to print the output or save it to a variable. E.g.

```py
import goslate
gs = goslate.Goslate()
text = input("please input the word you would like translated:\n")
print(gs.translate(text,'fr'))
```

Output:

```
please input the word you would like translated:
Hello
Bonjour
```

Check [the documentation](https://pypi.org/project/goslate/) for more details.